# Scaling image in background thread crashes - UIGraphicsImageRenderer

Tags: ios, swift, background

```
private func scale(image ciImage: CIImage?, for scale: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
    guard let ciImage = ciImage else {
        return UIImage()
    }

    let image = UIImage(ciImage: ciImage)
    let size = CGSize(width: image.size.width * scale, height: image.size.height * scale)

    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size)

    return renderer.image(actions: { (context) in
        image.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
    })
}
```

I am using this method to scale (and generate before that) images. This is done in background thread and the result is then dispatched back to main thread. However, on image.draw - sometimes 1 out of 10 times, the app crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

What am I doing wrong? Can I do that in background?

THANKS

Comment: You shouldn't do UI work in background thread, it should always be done inside the `.main` thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do any UI actions in a background thread. All UI changes must be done in the main thread

Use a dispatch Queue to work in main thread.Try it like this

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { 
   image.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
}
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53758353/7456236) answer to know why we use main thread to perform UI actions

Comment: If the `draw` method is for `UIImage`, that's not a view method and should work off the main thread, right? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10645307/thread-safety-of-uiimage https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/29031 https://ahmedk92.github.io/2019/03/23/Rendering-off-main-thread-in-iOS.html

Answer (score 1):

It looks like bug in CoreUI working with vector images. I'm having a similar issue right now with a following code

```
let scaledImage = renderer.image { _ in
        self.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: scaledImageSize))
}
```

leads to the following error:
[image]

[image]

Looking into `[_CUIThemeSVGRendition rawData]` you can see the following `release` statement:
[image]
I was not able to find related `retain` so I guess because of that memory is released twice which eventually leads to a crash.
It looks like `if(r8 & 0x3c) == 0x10)` is checking `bitmapEncoding` (see https://developer.limneos.net/index.php?ios=15.2.1&framework=CoreUI.framework&header=CUIThemeRendition.h) but I have no idea what should be inside. Maybe we should file a bug report to Apple.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33253379)